# How to set default values in Forms

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am Building a BlogApp and i am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to set the `Default Value` in forms.py for a `Form`.

views.py

```
def new_topic(request,user_id):
    profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,user_id=user_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:

        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
        new_topic.owner = profile
        new_topic.save()
        return redirect('mains:topics',user_id=user_id)

    #Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mains/new_topic.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['topic_no','topic_title']
```

**What have i tried :-**

I also did by using `initial` , BUT this didn't work for me.

```
form = DairyForm(request.POST,request.FILES,initial={'topic_title': 'Hello World'})
```

**The Problem**

Default value is not showing when i open form in browser.

I don't know what to do

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Did you pass initial for the form in the case of GET method (i. e. after this line `if request.method != 'POST':`)? from your example it appears you used it for the post request only.

Comment: Initial form is shown on GET  request and not on POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `initial` in the `GET` method, like this:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = TopicForm(initial={'topic_title': 'Hello World'})
else:
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values).

Comment: BUT when i  hide the `topic_title` from `forms` then it doesn't save Hello World ( I check in admin ).  Is there a way that, hidden form field can save default values ?

Comment: You can add default value in the model field to store default value on save of hidden fields

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `instance=TopicInstance` If you want any specific instance to be default. Or you want any other initial you should pass it like this

```
def new_topic(request,user_id):
    profiles = get_object_or_404(Profile,user_id=user_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm(initial={'topic_title': 'Hello World'})#When displaying it for first time
    else:

        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
        new_topic.owner = profile
        new_topic.save()
        return redirect('mains:topics',user_id=user_id)

    #Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mains/new_topic.html', context)
```